# const enum in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a React application that is using Typescript. Right now I'm running into an issue with const enum. Here's my enum:

```
export const enum Snack {
    Apple = 0,
    Banana = 1,
    Orange = 2,
    Other = 3
}
```

The service I'm trying to match up to isn't returning the value, but the index of the item within the enum. So, for instance, if the user is set to snack on an apple, the service is returning a 0 for that user instead of 'Apple'. Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
var snackIndex = UserSnack.type; // returning 0 in this example
var userSnack = Snack[snackIndex]; // would return 'Apple'
```

When I try something similar I'm getting the following error:

*error TS2476: A const enum member can only be accessed using a string literal.*

Since the service I'm receiving the data from doesn't return the string, I'm having issues getting this working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Just remove the `const` modifier.

`const` in an enum means the enum is fully erased during compilation. Const enum members are inlined at use sites. You can't index it by an arbitrary value.

In other words, the following TypeScript code

```ts
const enum Snack {
  Apple = 0,
  Banana = 1,
  Orange = 2,
  Other = 3
}

let snacks = [
  Snack.Apple,
  Snack.Banana,
  Snack.Orange,
  Snack.Other
];
```

is compiled to:

```js
let Snacks = [
    0 /* Apple */,
    1 /* Banana */,
    2 /* Orange */,
    3 /* Other */
];
```

---

Compare it with non-const version:

```ts
enum Snack {
  Apple = 0,
  Banana = 1,
  Orange = 2,
  Other = 3
}

let Snacks = [
  Snack.Apple,
  Snack.Banana,
  Snack.Orange,
  Snack.Other
];
```

it is compiled to:

```js
var Snack;
(function (Snack) {
    Snack[Snack["Apple"] = 0] = "Apple";
    Snack[Snack["Banana"] = 1] = "Banana";
    Snack[Snack["Orange"] = 2] = "Orange";
    Snack[Snack["Other"] = 3] = "Other";
})(Snack || (Snack = {}));
let Snacks = [
    Snack.Apple,
    Snack.Banana,
    Snack.Orange,
    Snack.Other
];
```

Source: [const enums @ typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYXNAok1BvAKBmJgDEBLAJ2hgF4YAiUgSWqgYBoiSBlOUMABM6jPgMGcCAXwIEEKGACU4Ac0QAbAIaUcCvDG7EKbEUyrRJJGGPDD6DG0MlSgA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYXNAok1BvAKBmJgDEBLAJ2hgF4YAiUgSWqgYBoiSBlOUMABM6jPgMGcCAXwIEEKGACU4Ac0QAbAIaUcCvDG7EKbEUyrRJJGGPDD6DG0MlSgA you won't see the value for the `const enum` declaration

Comment: For now, const enum use `preserveConstEnums: true`  in tsconfig will keep the same result like regular enum after compilation.

Comment: @Yuns there is a little difference after adding `preserveConstEnums: true` for `const enum`, the IIFE is created as in we have regular enum, but the compiled array remains same as in `const enum`.

Comment: @GouravPokharkar Thanks for your information, I only test with declare only enums above my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In modern TypeScript, you may not need an enum when an object with `as const` could suffice:

```
export const Snack = {
    Apple: 0,
    Banana: 1,
    Orange: 2,
    Other: 3,
} as const;
```

And now when you hover your mouse you see this type:
[image]

Enums can result in substantial code generation overhead. By integrating the `as const` keyword in TypeScript alongside Enums, we can significantly reduce the volume of generated code, leading to more streamlined and efficient development.

***Caution! Implementing `as const` alongside Enums removes the ability to utilize reverse mapping behavior. If your code relies on this functionality, it's advisable to avoid employing this approach.***