# How to get values of enum in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have a problem with getting values from enum. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
export const enum ComplianceType {
  ENGINEER_ASSESMENT = 'ENGINEER_ASSESMENT',
  CONSTRUCTION_COMPLIANCE = 'CONSTRUCTION_COMPLIANCE',
  ARCHITECTURE_ASSIGNMENT = 'ARCHITECTURE_ASSIGNMENT',
  BLUEPRINT_APPROVAL = 'BLUEPRINT_APPROVAL',
  THERMAL_COMPLIANCE = 'THERMAL_COMPLIANCE',
  ELECTRICITY_COMPLIANCE = 'ELECTRICITY_COMPLIANCE',
  TELECOMUNICATION_COMPLIANCE = 'TELECOMUNICATION_COMPLIANCE',
  WATER_COMPLIANCE = 'WATER_COMPLIANCE',
  OTHER_1 = 'OTHER_1',
  OTHER_2 = 'OTHER_2',
}
```

in my `.ts` file:

```
import { ICompliance, ComplianceType } from 'app/shared/model/compliance.model';
```

And i tried this one:

```
complianceTypeList: ComplianceType;
```

I don't get how to get values from enum in typescript. Any advice ?

Comment: Did you try removing const from enum?? As like mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227401/const-enum-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

You should not assign it, or try to assign [Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) as variables. Just `export enum ComplianceType` will do.

```
export enum ComplianceType {
  ENGINEER_ASSESMENT = 'ENGINEER_ASSESMENT',
  CONSTRUCTION_COMPLIANCE = 'CONSTRUCTION_COMPLIANCE',
  ARCHITECTURE_ASSIGNMENT = 'ARCHITECTURE_ASSIGNMENT',
  BLUEPRINT_APPROVAL = 'BLUEPRINT_APPROVAL',
  THERMAL_COMPLIANCE = 'THERMAL_COMPLIANCE',
  ELECTRICITY_COMPLIANCE = 'ELECTRICITY_COMPLIANCE',
  TELECOMUNICATION_COMPLIANCE = 'TELECOMUNICATION_COMPLIANCE',
  WATER_COMPLIANCE = 'WATER_COMPLIANCE',
  OTHER_1 = 'OTHER_1',
  OTHER_2 = 'OTHER_2',
}
```

From there, you can simply import the `Enums` on the Class, or component, that requires it.

```
import { ComplianceType } from 'app/shared/model/compliance.model';
```

Works perfectly fine over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7cq21?file=src/app/hello.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(EnumType);` if you want to access the keys of your enums, or `Object.values(EnumType);` if you want to have access to its values. Nevertheless, it looks like you are trying to assign an entire Enum to a single Enum property type here

You can do this:

```
complianceType: ComplianceType;

complianceType = ComplianceType.ENGINEER_ASSESMENT;
```

But you can't assign a type to a variable of this type, basically. That does not make sens.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an Enum value by treating it like an array and accessing its value by using the key:

```
ComplianceType["ARCHITECTURE_ASSIGNMENT"]
```

Should give you the value.