# detect comparison out of enum range

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, with a function returning an enum

```
const enum STATUS {
    stOK = 0,
    srERROR = 1
}

getStatus () : STATUS {
    return this.status;
}

CheckStatus () {
     if (this.getStatus () == 999) {
          // never reached, not in the enum range ...
     }
}
```

I would like that usage of the function to be mark as wrong, since 999 is not a value allowed in the enum, but I am not able to make this happen

Comment: Number enums can be used as flags: `const status = STATUS.val1 | STATUS.val2`, so value of type STATUS can have numeric value higher than any of the enum values.

Comment: @Lesiak I don't understand your comment. You mean that using status as you say I can have a value out of range ? But I don't want to do it, I just want not being able to do it. (It being reported as an error)

Comment: my comment tried to explain why any number is assignable to a numeric enum. Even TS team members agree that this design has downsides (loose type checking). See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362#issuecomment-412198938

Comment: @Lesiak OK, I got it, thank you by the reference !!   But may be a **const** enum should handled different

Comment: This is not the meanig of the const enum. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227401/const-enum-in-typescript. Also note that string enums cannot be used as flags, so this may be a solution you are looking for.